# EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail ignored Query

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sp-send-dbmail

I have a code to send Birthday Emails to Customers, the query works fine, but the SQL Mail server always send a Birthday Email to all Customers, even he has no Birthday

```
use Insurance
go


select 
  Customer.CustomerID
  ,Customer.FirstName
  ,Customer.LastName
  ,Customer.Birthday
  ,Customer.Email

from Customer
where Customer.CustomerID = Customer.CustomerID and 
                DAY([Birthday]) = DAY(GETDATE())
                AND MONTH([Birthday]) = MONTH(GETDATE())

declare @Receipientlist nvarchar(4000)

set @Receipientlist =
      STUFF((select ';' + Email FROM dbo.Customer FOR XML PATH('')),1,1,'')



EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail @profile_name='test',
    @recipients=@Receipientlist,
    @subject='Insurance',
    @body='Happy Birthday.
      Today is your Birthday.'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query at the top of your batch has nothing to do with your statement that executes `msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail`. If you only want to email customer's who's birthday it is, you need to filter in the statement that creates the recipients (and you don't need the previous statement):

```
DECLARE @RecipientList nvarchar(4000);

--I removed the CustomerID = CustomerID clause, as it'll always equal itself,
--apart from when it's value is NULL (and I doubt it'll ever be NULL)
SET @RecipientList = STUFF((SELECT N';' + Email
                             FROM dbo.Customer
                             WHERE DAY([Birthday]) = DAY(GETDATE())
                               AND MONTH([Birthday]) = MONTH(GETDATE())
                             FOR XML PATH(N''),TYPE).value('.','nvarchar(4000)'), 1, 1,N'');

EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail @profile_name = 'test',
                             @recipients = @RecipientList,
                             @subject = 'Insurance',
                             @body = 'Happy Birthday.
            Today is your Birthday.';
```

I've also changed the way that the value from the subquery is returned, used `TYPE` and the `value` clauses. Email addresses can contain some special characters, and these would have been escaped without the usage of `TYPE` (for example `&` would become `&amp;`). *(I've also corrected the spelling of `@RecipientList`.)*

Comment: if i implement this code i have a error in Line @RecipientList Incorrect syntax near ';'.

Comment: I was missing a parenthsis. @jimmy. I didn't test this, as I didn't have any sample data. Fixed (but you should be able to debug a simple problem like that too :) )